# How do pointers work with doubly-linked lists in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, doubly-linked-list

if I create the following struct:

```
typedef struct node {
    int a;
    char b[100][15];
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
} Scope;
```

Must I use a pointer to initialize my head_node?  Currently this is my initialize function:

```
Scope initScope() {
    Scope head;
    head.a = 1;
    head.prev = NULL;
    head.next = NULL;
    return head;
}
```

In some function I would say

```
Scope head = initScope();
```

This seems okay to me so far, but I'm not sure how I will create a new node.  I'm guessing I would need a pointer of type Scope.  I would have to malloc it of size Scope and then initialize its values.  Should I do the same when creating the head?  The underlying question I'm trying to answer is what is the purpose of a pointer here?  What if in the definition of my struct I had written

```
*Scope
```

instead of

```
Scope
```

?  If I need to use pointers to create nodes then why not make the struct a pointer?  From my understanding pointers just allow me to manipulate memory, so what is left behind when I create a node and move on?

Answer (score 0):

> This seems okay to me so far, but I'm not sure how I will create a new node.

The `prev` and `next` members of a `Scope` object must point to other `Scope` objects to create a linked list.

These objects may be in a statically allocated array of objects or dynamically allocated objects.

1. Creating a linked list from a statically allocated array

   ```
   Scope scopes[10];
   scopes[0].prev = NULL;
   scopes[9].next = NULL;
   for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i )
   {
       scopes[i].next = &(scopes[i+1]);
       scopes[i+1].pref = &(scopes[i]);
   }
   ```
2. Creating a linked list from dynamically allocated objects

   ```
   Scope* node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
   node->next = node->prev = NULL;
   for ( int i = 0; i < 9; ++i )
   {
      Scope* temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp));
      temp->prev = NULL;
      temp->next = node;
      node->prev = temp;
      node = temp;
   }
   ```

   You can also dynamically allocate all the objects using one call.

   ```
   Scope* scopes = malloc(10*sizeof(*scopes));
   ```

   and then treat it similarly to a statically allocated array.

   You'll need to use the right calls to `free` depending on which method you use to allocate the objects.

Comment: So I would be using a pointer to create nodes?  The first node would have null pointers, and every node after would be linked to the next pointer?  So really I'm just using struct to allocate a certain sized block of memory?

Comment: Pointers point to objects. I am not sure what you mean by *So I would be using a pointer to create nodes?* If there is only one node, it's `next` and `prev` members will be NULL. Otherwise, they won't. Yes, you are using a `struct` to allocate a certain sized block of memory.

Comment: What I mean is that rather than saying `int = 5`, I'll be saying `int *ptr = malloc(sizeof(int)); &ptr = 5;` so essentially I'm sectioning off memory of size int.  Now applying this idea to linked lists, I have to do it this way or else I would have a unique variable name for every node right?  Or I'd have an array of nodes that each have a unique index?  I think I'm beginning to understand why I need to use a pointer for nodes after the head.

Comment: @Pareod, you are heading in the right direction. The only thing that is not right is that you need to use `*ptr = 5;`, not `&ptr = 5;`.

Comment: But ptr is pointing to a block of memory of size int, so wouldn't `&ptr = 5;` put the number 5 in that memory block?  Saying `ptr = 5` would change what block of memory the pointer is looking at I thought.  For example, `currentNode = currentNode->prev;` doesn't set the current memory equal to prev, it changes where currentNode is looking.

Comment: @Pareod, I said `*ptr = 5;`, not `ptr = 5;`. Please spend a bit of time on reading about pointers and dereferencing pointers in C/C++. SO overflow is not good for such topics.